# Is there an easy way to calculate the gaussian fit for data that has been cut off by pixel saturation?

Tags: python, gaussian, astropy, function-fitting

I have image data for a flash of light where a few of the pixels have reached 255 at the centre of the flash. What would be the best way to go about fitting a 2D gaussian to the data that isn't at 255 in order to model what the hypothetical pixel value of the pixels would be.

I have been playing around with `astropy.convolution`, and the `interpolate_replace_nans` function, but this always returns values below 255 rather than the expected value of above 255.

**The surface plot of the data**
[image: surface plot]

The surface plot of the data clearly follows a single gaussian shape, with the top cut off; is there a simple way to work out the parameters of the gaussian to reconstruct what the values should be?

Answer (score 0):

If you mask out the pixels that are saturated, you can then [fit](https://docs.astropy.org/en/stable/modeling/fitting.html#simple-2-d-model-fitting) a [2D Gaussian model](https://docs.astropy.org/en/stable/api/astropy.modeling.functional_models.Gaussian2D.html) to the data.

The masking can be as simple as not passing the bad data to the fitter, since the fitter expects to receive x,y coordinates and a corresponding z value.

(the convolution approach is not correct here; it can never return a value larger than was in the original data)

Answer (score 0):

You can model the saturated gaussian, fit the data with the model, and recover the original gaussian with the fitting parameter.

Here is an example:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.optimize import minimize
from numba import njit

@njit
def get_model(mu_x, mu_y, sig_x, sig_y, amp, cutoff, image_size):
    """
    simulate a 2D gaussian were the value higher than cutoff
        were saturated.
    """
    dom_x = -1 / 2 / sig_x ** 2
    dom_y = -1 / 2 / sig_y ** 2
    result = np.empty(image_size)
    for x in range(image_size[0]):
        for y in range(image_size[1]):
            gx = (x - mu_x)**2 * dom_x
            gy = (y - mu_y)**2 * dom_y
            g = amp * np.exp(gx + gy)
            g = min(g, cutoff)
            result[x, y] = g
    return result

def cost(args, data):
    model = get_model(*args, data.shape)
    return np.power(model - data, 2).sum()

img = get_model(25, 25, 10, 5, 300, 255, (70, 70))

result = minimize(
    cost, x0=(25, 25, 1, 1, 255, 255),
    args=(img)
)

fit = get_model(*result.x, img.shape)
gauss = get_model(
    *result.x[:-1],
    cutoff=np.inf,  # set cutoff to inf == no saturation
    image_size=img.shape
)


plt.figure(figsize=(10, 4))
plt.subplot(131).imshow(img, vmin=0, vmax=300)
plt.title("data")
plt.subplot(132).imshow(fit, vmin=0, vmax=300)
plt.title("fitting result")
plt.subplot(133).imshow(gauss, vmin=0, vmax=300)
plt.title("gaussian from fit")
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```